Get-IISAppPool returns zero instances with pwsh.exe but many with powershell.exe
I created a Windows scheduled task that executes a script with PowerShell like this:
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden C:\script.ps1

The task is configured to run as SYSTEM and the script itself generates a small HTML page with a list of running ISS instances using the Get-IISAppPool command.
After successfully testing the script on a test host, I thought I'm smart and changed the powerhell.exe command to pwsh.exe before deploying it to another host. The script still ran and generated HTML code, but always listed 0 ISS instances.
For some reason, the Get-IISAppPool command returns a empty list with pwsh.exe (PowerShell 7.2.4), but powershell.exe (5.1.17763.5696) correctly returns all IIS instances.
Does anyone know the explanation for this difference in behavior?

You have to stick to PowerShell 5.1 which is .NET Framework based. The IIS related cmdlets are also .NET Framework based. pwsh.exe, however, uses .NET Core which is incompatible.

PowerShell Core, while being cross-platform, may not have full compatibility with all Windows-specific modules. Get-IISAppPool is a cmdlet from the WebAdministration module, which might not be fully supported or implemented in PowerShell Core.
